# How are jumper wires called in French?

Tags: vocabulaire, informatique

I am looking for the French technical translation for “jumper wires”. These are special wires you use in electronics to directly plug into pins:

[image: jumper wires]

Throughout research on Internet points to wires for horse riding or clothing...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would precisely call what you have represented *nappe de raccordement à connecteurs individuels*, *nappe de connexion femelle/femelle*, or simply *câble de connexion*.

That's a *nappe* or *câble en nappe* because the wires are joined together in a flat manner (ribbon cable).

I add *à connecteurs individuels* because the connectors on the ends are not inline but independents.

*Femelle/femelle* precises what kind of connector are at each end.

When not in a ribbon, these wires are also often called *câbles de pontage* ou *cables d'expérimentation*.

I would recommend against using *fils* but prefer *câble* here, especially as there are multiple wires joint together, which is the definition of a *câble* at least when talking about electronics or electrical components. The [tlfi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/c%C3%A2ble) states: *Ensemble de conducteurs distincts, mécaniquement solidaires*

Comment: Just to make it clear, the difference between a "câble" and a "fil"  is the size. A "câble" is bigger than a "fil". So he might wanna use "fil" there.

Comment: @milk2go I beg to differ, the object depicted here cannot be named a *fil*. It is a *câble* because it is made of multiple jointed wires.

Answer (score 2):

In order of which I would prefer using as a french:

1. Fils de raccordement
2. Fils de connexion
3. Fils de liaison

[traduction site](http://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/jumper+wire.html)

"Nappe de raccordement à connecteurs individuels." as said before is pretty great too as it's more precise, but I doubt anyone would actually say it (unless one really needs to be more precise). It's more of a written term.
I've searched for those on french websites and they really call them just "fils" or "fils de connexion" etc. nothing special. I've seen "câbles cavalier" and "câbles dupont" at some places too. (amazon.fr likes these two)

Answer (score 1):

We would say : "Fils connecteurs". This is the most accurate translation.